# How to create to sub columns in SQL database using the PHP script?

Tags: php, sql

I want to create a database which consists of a column named `Day`. That `Day`-column should consist of the sub-columns `slot1`, `slot2`, `slot3`.

Comment: There are no "sub-columns" in SQL. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Thank you @Amadan .  I want create a table in sql that consists of Column day.In that table that column should consists of three columns slot1 slot2 slot3.Can you give a partial  solution for this?

Comment: And again, there is no such thing as sub-columns. You can have three columns, and you can consider them together in certain calculations. You can't have them be a part of another column. There is no way for a column to consist of other columns. This is almost certainly an XY problem. What is it you actually want to do?

Comment: Thank you once again @Amadan.Iam designing a student attendance project.   Actually i want to create a database  that should have columns student id ,student name,Day1,day2,day3.......up to end of the month.A day should have three slots 9am to 10am   ,10am to 2:00pm and 2:00pm to 4:00pm .

Comment: This is not a great database structure. I would likely normalise the relation and have one table for student (with id and name), and one table with student id, date, slot id, and associated data. But it does depend on how you're going to use it.

Comment: ok @Amadan thanks for your suggestion.